# Regarding Ropsten Setup

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, testnets, ropsten

I am using geth version1.6.5...Trying to set up Ropsten using the following command...

```
 geth --networkid=3 --syncmode=fast --cache=1024 console
```

It shows the following commands

```
  INFO [06-15|15:54:39] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.6.5-stable-cf87713d/linux-amd64/go1.8.1
  INFO [06-15|15:54:39] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/toshiba/.ethereum/geth/chaindata cache=1024 handles=1024
  INFO [06-15|15:54:56] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 3 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 0 EIP155: 10 EIP158: 10 Metropolis: <nil> Engine: unknown}"
  INFO [06-15|15:54:56] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/home/toshiba/.ethereum/geth/ethash count=3
  INFO [06-15|15:54:56] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/home/toshiba/.ethash               count=2
  INFO [06-15|15:54:56] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=3
 INFO [06-15|15:54:56] Loaded most recent local header          number=1121759 hash=bdf4d6…ebcdec td=747686182747507
 INFO [06-15|15:54:56] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0       hash=419410…ca4a2d td=1048576
 INFO [06-15|15:54:56] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=1121676 hash=80f4d5…3ed841 td=747645006524095
 INFO [06-15|15:54:56] Starting P2P networking 
 INFO [06-15|15:54:58] UDP listener up                          self=enode://2fc98df1f0e5f3baaa527c2acd579e3d76772681ccc00f4e479a688d519416e003693db537aa37a2aac7fe22ca781f11c8b95654dc960266262edea3b0a99d42@[::]:30303
 INFO [06-15|15:54:58] RLPx listener up                         self=enode://2fc98df1f0e5f3baaa527c2acd579e3d76772681ccc00f4e479a688d519416e003693db537aa37a2aac7fe22ca781f11c8b95654dc960266262edea3b0a99d42@[::]:30303
INFO [06-15|15:54:58] IPC endpoint opened: /home/toshiba/.ethereum/geth.ipc 
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.6.5-stable-cf87713d/linux-amd64/go1.8.1
coinbase: 0x124e0fc135b5137c113d385487b56da143a9b66e
 at block: 0 (Thu, 01 Jan 1970 05:30:00 IST)
datadir: /home/toshiba/.ethereum
modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0
```

While checking the blocknumber using the command
     `eth.blockNumber`
 it returns zero..since I haven't downloaded any full block...

I am also using the Mist version 0.8.10..I can verify the blocks downloading in Mist too..

Should I able to test my dapps using this Ropsten setup with Mist?

Does it require full node to run dapps??

I have tried by omitting the syncmode from the command,it automatically diverts to fast mode??
so How can I download full node??

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to verify the number of blocks downloaded through the console using the command `eth.blockNumber`, ‘Loaded most recent local full block’ will always show ‘0’ , which doesn’t mean that your blocks are not being downloaded. It will only show the correct blocks once all the blocks are downloaded.

Refer this for more

https://medium.com/@crissimrobert/a-guide-to-ropsten-testnet-setup-f8952d615417